# How can I publish serverless application on AWS faster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-mvc, aws-serverless

I do not know how this question is logic but if there is anyway to solve this issue, it will cause to not waste my time.

I have a ASP.net core application that consist of many libraries like jquery, modernizer and etc. All of them stored in lib folder in wwwroot folder.

When I start publishing on AWS (with AWS Toolkit) it start zipping and publishing on the server as usual.

The point is that it will take a lot of time for zipping all of the libraries. these library does not any change during the project and I just change some pages or classes. 
 
Is there any way to cancel zipping some folders to publish faster?

Comment: Can you describe your publishing process a little more? What services are you using? What are the details of your server/infrastructure? I ask this because if for instance your publishing process spins up an EC2 instance to run your application on, you could create and publish an AMI with all of the libraries that your application needs.

Comment: since this is a serverless application you can use a buildspec and ask it to resolve those packages after the uploading happens and even you can exclude the packages you dont want to upload in serverless file. Please check their documentation for that. Meanwhile to do the first method that i have mentioned it is better to provision a ci/cd mechanism like codebuild and codepipeline. It will help you to overcome this problem.

Comment: @PrestonM
Thanks for replying. I am publishing project via AWS Toolkit (context menu : Publish To AWS). I am using some libraries in my web project like jquer, propper, moment,require.js and etc). Can you tell me how can I use AMI ?

Comment: @SameeraPiyasundara
Thanks for replying. I think it is best solution. Is there a link that I can read more about it ? Please write it as answer if it is possible for you . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this in your AWS serverless template to remove unwanted packages from the bundle.

```
package:
  exclude:
   - scripts/**
   - dynamodb/tables/**
   - policies/**
   - dynamodb/seeds/**
```

If you are using a CI/CD methodology then you can ask the code builder to use a script in a root folder structure to run your package resolvers and all. Please refer this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/how-to-create-pipeline.html)